# insert an element into a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, django

I have declared an empty list and I want to append dictionaries through a `for` loop by using the `extend()` method, but I end with a list with the same content in all its positions (the same dictionary)

This is the code:

```
def get_tasks(self, actor, task_state):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(actor=actor.id, state=task_state)
    tasks_to_return = []
    task_data = {}

    for task in tasks:
        task_data['name'] = getattr(task, 'name')
        task_data['description'] = getattr(task, 'description')
        task_data['start_date'] = getattr(task, 'start_date')
        task_data['finish_date'] = getattr(task, 'finish_date')
        task_data['situation'] = task.get_situation()
        tasks_to_return.extend(task_data)

    return tasks_to_return
```

If I change `extend()` for `append()`, the result is even worst.

Comment: shouldn't you be creating a new dict in each loop iteration to append to `tasks_to_return`? Also I think you want to be using `append` instead of extend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you each time add the *same* dictionary to the list: indeed you only change the key/values of that dictionary, and add that dictionary a second time, etc.

Furthermore by using `extend`, you actually add a *iterable* of elements to a list. A dictionary is an *iterable*: you iterate over the keys.

So what you should do is (1) construct a new dictionary each time, and (2) use `append` instead of extend:

```
for task in tasks:
    task_data = {}
    task_data['name'] = getattr(task, 'name')
    task_data['description'] = getattr(task, 'description')
    task_data['start_date'] = getattr(task, 'start_date')
    task_data['finish_date'] = getattr(task, 'finish_date')
    task_data['situation'] = task.get_situation()
    tasks_to_return.append(task_data)
```

We can also improve the code, for instance instead of setting the key-value pairs, we can do this at the construction of the dictionary. You use `getattr(..)`, but this is not necessary here: we can use `task.name` instead of `getattr(task, 'name')`, so a more elegant approach is probably:

```
tasks_to_return = []
task_data = {}
```

```
for task in tasks:
    task_data = {
        'name': task.name,
        'description': task.description,
        'start_date': task.start_date,
        'finish_date': task.finish_date,
        'situation': task.situation
    }
    tasks_to_return.append(task_data)
```

Now since the list is initially empty, we can also use *list comprehension*:

```
tasks_to_return = [ {
        'name': task.name,
        'description': task.description,
        'start_date': task.start_date,
        'finish_date': task.finish_date,
        'situation': task.situation
    } for task in tasks]
```

Comment: Fantastic! everything works handsomely. Today was a very productive day for learning. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your `extend` or `append` adds the original reference to `task_data`, whose contents you keep changing.  Instead, either make a new empty object for `task_data`, or append a copy of the one you reuse:

```
import copy
...
    tasks_to_return.append(copy.copy(task_data))
```